# Displaying a day format from a datetime query

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Not sure what the terminology is so been unable to search the problem. I am wishing to extract the day from a datetime query (SQL), asp.net, c# etc and then display as in the following examples.

- Date: 21/01/2019(UK) or 01/21/2019(US) display as 21st instead of 21
- Date: 25/02/2018(UK) or 02/25/2018(US) display as 25th.

I have no problem extracting the day, I just need to know if it is possible to use the syntax as shown? Or what this syntax is even called?

Comment: Seems like Ordinals is the term I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use momentjs format `date.format('Do')`

```
let dateStr = '21/01/2019';
let date = moment(dateStr, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(date.format('Do'));

dateStr = '02/25/2018';
date = moment(dateStr, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log(date.format('Do'));
```

```js
let dateStr = '21/01/2019';
let date = moment(dateStr, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(date.format('Do'));

dateStr = '02/25/2018';
date = moment(dateStr, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log(date.format('Do'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: The question seems related C#, not Javascript.

Comment: he use asp.net, if he didnt want to use javascript, i will delete answer